# Symmetric part of A contributes to quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, symmetry

In my statistics note, when it talks about quadratic forms, it goes on saying:

"$x^tAx=\frac12x^t(A+A^t)x$ implies that only the symmetric part of A contributes to the quadratic form."

I am having hard time understanding the meaning of the sentence. I understand $(A + A^t)$ is symmetric but what it means when it says "only symmetric part contributes to quadratic form"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words: take any matrix $A$, and any anti-symmetric matrix $B$.  For all real vectors $x$, we have
$$
x^TA x = x^T(A + B)x
$$
That is, changing the anti-symmetric part of a matrix does not change the resulting quadratic form.  So, the quadratic form is determined entirely from the symmetric part.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is not symmetric. Then one can argue that there exists a symmetric matrix $A_s$ such that $x^TAx = x^TA_sx$. So what is $A_s$?

$A_s = \frac{1}{2}A + \frac{1}{2}A^T$

$A_s$ can thus be derived from your equality:

$$
x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx = x^T(\frac{1}{2}A + \frac{1}{2}A^T)x 
$$